# Why is sass file not updating on css file?

Tags: css, sass, compiled

So here is the scenario, I have "main.scss" file inside "sass" folder and "style.css" file inside "css" folder. I have also already installed the "node-sass", "npm". When i try to compile the sass file into the css file through the terminal. It shows that it is successfully compiled but i can't see any updates on the css file. [[image: This is the compiled file][1]]

```
{
  "name": "natours",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "compile:sass": "node-sass sass/main.scss css/style.css"
  },
  "author": "anjan",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

As soon as i compile the file, i get the package-lock.json file on my folder. I am also assuming this might be causing the update to stop on css file.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

C:\Users\HP\Desktop\advanced-css-course-master\Natours\starter> sass --watch sass/main.scss:css/style.css

Comment: This should be given in a comment, otherwise explain how this should help his question